# i'm trying to send a https request through a proxy with apache httpclient,but i can't find the headers on the proxy side

Tags: java, android, https, proxy, httpclient

i'm trying to send a https request through a proxy with apache httpclient,but i can't find the headers on the proxy side

```
HttpClient httpClient =new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("10.1.1.100", 8080);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
get.addHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "222222");
HttpResponse hr = defaultHttpClient.execute(get);
```

the proxy side only find proxy-connection and user-agent:
Proxy-Connection:[Keep-Alive] User-Agent:[Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)]

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not how you authenticate to a proxy. Second, those headers are added to the `get` request (not to the `proxy`). Finally, this is based on an example the [HttpClient examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) - specifically  [`ClientProxyAuthentication`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java) and updated to use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (and modified to use an `URL`)

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("10.1.1.100", 8080),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build()) {
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(),
            url.getProtocol());
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("10.1.1.100", 8080);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy)
            .build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url.getPath());
    httpget.setConfig(config);
    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine()
            + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);

    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target,
            httpget)) {

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html
 i use bearer tokens to  authorize the client (http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html) ,so the "Proxy-Authorization"  is necessary in every request`s  header.

Comment: And where do you see in the documentation that Apache http client supports your draft ietf oauth protocol?